# genymotion can't run on eclipse? engine failed error

Tags: eclipse, adt, genymotion

pls help me I have installed genymotion succesfully but it seems that i configured the wrong directory which gives me an "Exception (VBoxManage): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Genymobile/reg": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
Initialize Engine: failed"

Please somebody tell me how do i reset the directory

I have tried uninstalling he plugin but no luck

Answer (score -1):

In Eclipse go to menu Window => Preferences. In the Preferences dialog go to Genymobile => Genymotion. On the right pane set your Genymotion directory. As an example mine is C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion.
Afterwards hit OK and you are ready to go.